# Object detection - Ignore specific image zones during training

Tags: keras, object-detection, faster-rcnn

Im trying to use the Faster R-CNN Algorithm for vehicle detection using keras.

I have a dataset containing different folders with every folder containing multiple images. I've managed to transform the annotation files for the images into a CSV file for training process. the annotation files contain extra information about region to be ignored in the images during the training (black zones in the attached image). The image show the bounding boxes for the vehicles along with the ignored zones in the image in a test example based on the information obtained from the annotation file for this image.

Is there a way to specify the specific zones to focus on or to ignore while during training of the algorithm?

[image]

Comment: is it possible to assign them a new label "NA" and training it ? and the purpose of ignoring them ? 
may be you can add class weights with high weights for other classes and least weight for "NA"

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Thank you for your response, in fact I don't have access to the cars hidden behind the ignored zones. The XML annotations provide information about the bounding boxes in the image and also these ignored area in the image which after drawing them I've noticed that they hide certain vehicle in the image which are not supposed to be considered while training the algorithm I guess. I want to tell the algorithm to ignore these zones for every image.

Comment: yea. did you try, assigning a label to the ignored zones and assigning a class weight to them during training ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan no not yet, I'll do that and get back to you, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> The loss function is modified to not penalize predictions inside these ignore annotation areas as false positives during training.

This phrase is of bellow article (Sec.3.2), a good way but I don't know how to do it.

> Vandersteegen, Maarten, Kristof Van Beeck, and Toon Goedemé. "Super accurate low latency object detection on a surveillance UAV." 2019 16th International Conference on Machine Vision Applications (MVA). IEEE, 2019.